# 2016 Honda Accord Sport

Tags: honda, brakes, accord, caliper

I have a 2016 Honda Accord Sport with 7,000 miles.

Recently, I put the car in reverse and she was stalling like the emergency brake was on. Then all the way home as I drove it was like something was pulling me back. Every time I take my foot off the gas to slow down the car slows down DRAMATICALLY before I can even touch the brake. Then when I pull on my emergency brake it just flops like it just fall right back down like a magnet was under it. Honda says its the brake caliper that was full of dust and dirt and will replace it with a new one.

My question is, should I believe them?

Is something going on with my car that shouldn't be?

The car is new with 7,000 miles.

Comment: Your car is under warranty. Take it to the dealership and let them fix the issue. If cleaning out the brakes and adjustment doesn't fix it, take it back and have them fix it again. Really, there is no reason for them to be lying to you. The issues they fix will be covered by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds like one or both of your rear brake calipers (assuming that the emergency brake acts on the rear brakes on that car) is sticking or that the emergency brake is not releasing fully. If you put your hand close to the rear wheels after driving you'll probably notice that one or both of the wheels is noticeably hot – maybe even hot enough to burn you.

When the caliper sticks it causes the brakes to drag and it this also means that emergency brake doesn't have anything to push against. That's why the handle feels like it isn't doing anything. Another explanation of the problem could be something causing the emergency brake to hang up – one possibility might be water getting into he brake cable and freezing. Do you live in a cold climate?

You're right that a new car *shouldn't* have problems like this, but sometimes it happens and that's why there is a warranty. The dealer (and Honda) *want* to fix this for you – most people understand that out of the millions of cars sold each year that some will have problems and the industry knows that if they are responsible and proactive in solving the problems that that will outweigh the fact that there was a problem in most people's mind.

So take the car in and get it fixed, but also ask the for an explanation of why the problem happened – it might be hard to track down if the problem is weather related, but they should be able to tell you what they checked and what they found or didn't find. Try to make sense of what you're told and you can bring it back here for an explanation and/or sanity check.